# C# Docusign API - Getting Remote Signing View URL

Tags: docusignapi

After running the console app, our users get an email with the signing link to Docusign making them remote signers.

What I want to be able to do is get those links from their emails.

I did some research and this is what each url is made of

> https://demo.docusign.net/Member/EmailStart.aspx?
>
> **a**=65d11cf7-d3b7-49a1-8000-6192b6227d71& <<< Unique Activity ID? Always different in all URLs
>
> **acct**=a0e816ac-3919-475e-a826-34c2c33f90e7& <<< Some kind of role ID (stays same between envelopes and users of the same role, I have it
> for my roles..just don't know how to get it programmatically
>
> **er**=62378ec0-39ce-495e-84e4-e0e598fab3cc& <<<< envelopesApi.ListRecipients(.....) .Signers[n].RecipientIdGuid, able to get it
>
> **espei**=30cec285-39cd-45a3-bb8e-7bd0560dcd80 <<<< ENVELOPE ID, able to get it

The first parameter is the main focus of my question - it is a total mistery what is it and how to get it

The second parameter looks like a role_id, but I don't know how to get it other than hard-coding values for each of my roles

The other two parameters aren't a concern.

Does anybody know how to get ahold of the first two parameters using the C# Docusign API?

Or even better, is there a way to get the recipients signing url links using the same API?

Comment: What are you going to do with the signing URL? DocuSign lets you obtain signing URL if its an embedded recipient. For remote signers there is no way to obtain the signing URL. Only signer will know the URL.

Comment: Save it in a database (CRM) and then it will get retrieved by the MVC App and displayed to users as a list. I guess the MVC app could embed the signing but the thing is I want them to use the DocuSign UI, not mine.

Comment: Unfortunately Docusign does not support what you are asking. What you can do is mark the recipient as an embedded recipient when you create the envelope. Then whenever you want to display the Signing page on your MVC app, make a call to the createRecipient:EnvelopeViews api and retrieve the signing URL.  The embedding signing URL will only be active for 5 minutes. You can display it in a iFrame in your APP.  Look at this [page](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#OptimizingUX) for optimizing your embedded signing experience

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441040/docusign-rest-api-c-sharp-get-permanent-links-for-signers/44452163#44452163

Comment: No, my solution is not embedded.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the signing URL you will have to set the recipient as an [embedded recipient](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#EmbeddedSigning).

After the envelope is created, use the [createRecipient:EnvelopeViews](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/) api to retrieve the Signing URL.

You have to set the recipient **clientUserId** parameter to mark a recipient as an embedded recipient.

**Request**

```
{
  "userName": "name",
  "email": "examble@email.com",
  "clientUserId": "clientUserId",
  "authenticationMethod": "email",
  "returnUrl": "your app url"
}
```

Comment: Can it be done if  I don't have an app to embed the signing into? It's a console project.
_Embedded Signing - or the Recipient View workflow - allows users to sign directly through your app or website. When you embed your recipients you are telling the DocuSign platform your app will generate signing URLs, authenticate your recipients, present the signing request, and re-direct once the transaction is complete._

Comment: Yes you can retrieve the URL from the console app by calling the [createRecipient:EnvelopeViews](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/) api. It all depends on what you are planning to do with the URL.