# DocuSign: Rest API C# get permanent links for signers

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using DocuSign's REST API to create envelopes in embedded signing mode. With the function CreateRecipientView i get only a temporary link. But i would prefer to get an permanent link like in the notification mail. How can i get this link/URL?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check/accept the best answer for your question and upvote all useful answers that you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting permanent signing links is not possible using the DocuSign rest API.

For remote signers, only the signer can receive the signing link through email. No one else will have access to the signing URL.

Setting permanent signing/access link is possible with "embeddedRecipientStartURL" by using a captive recipient aka "clientUserId" and your own URL endpoint whereby you authenticate your users and determine if they can access the envelope via a Request Recipient View.

Documentation [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/).

You can also request emails be sent per captive recipients as well as many other "Portal" centric options that put you in full control of the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

To give your signers permanent links, your application creates the links by itself. Eg `myapp.myserver.com/signing_links/95a086f7-a76e-40ec-938e-987be996d220`

The number should be a guid, not a database record key. This is needed to prevent someone from guessing what one of these permanent links is, so they can't read (or sign!) someone else's documents.

When someone opens their browser to go to one of the signer links, your application looks up the guid in the your app's database. The database record will include the DocuSign envelope_id and the recipient_id that the link represents.

Next your app uses that data to request an embedded recipient view link from DocuSign. Then (if you get a good response back from DocuSign), your app redirects the user's browser to the signing page on DocuSign.

(You'd get back an error from DocuSign if the recipient had already signed, or the envelope had been voided, etc.)

Guess what? The above is more or less how DocuSign gives out the "permanent" links in its emails--those links always redirect to one of the 5-minutes-only signing ceremony links.

Remember that you need to authenticate the signers, or include additional authentication options in your envelope, since you don't know who is going to end up pressing one of your app's signer links.

Answer (score 0):

Setting vs Getting permanent signing/access link is possible with "embeddedRecipientStartURL" by using a captive recipient aka "clientUserId" and your own URL endpoint whereby you authenticate your users and determine if they can access the envelope via a Request Recipient View.

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Signers%20Recipient.htm

You can also request emails be sent per captive recipients as well as many other "Portal" centric options that put you in full control of the user experience.

So Net/Net, LarryK and CodingDawg are correct, each from a specific view. It ultimately is up to you to decide which way works best for your application and users.