# Is there an Agent URL or Redirect available for the Agent Signature Assignment

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the Agent Managed envelopes functionality.  Everything is working exactly the way it should be.

I have an issue however where the Agent who is supposed to assign the next Signatory sometimes does not see the e-mail they are receiving to do the assignment and they inadvertently delete this e-mail.

Ideally they would see the e-mail and open it to assign the next signatory.

But, they receive several per day and sometimes one gets missed.

**Is there a URL or redirect associated with the UI that the agent sees for this specific envelopes e-mail?**

I would like to retrieve it and list the envelopes in my application that the agent needs to assign signatories to.

That way they can see which ones they have not assigned and navigate to the assignment UI from my application?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! PLEASE accept/check the best answer for each of your questions. Upvotes are also a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this.

1. Use one of the methods discussed above to identify the envelope that
   needs a signatory added.
2. Use the [/recipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/) endpoint to retrieve all of the recipient info
   for that envelope.
3. Identify the recipient that needs their information updated.
4. Use the [/recipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update/) endpoint again with a PUT request sending an object with the updated information. It is important that the routing order be set to the same number as the routing order for the agent and that you add the following query param or the signer that you have just updated will not receive an email. resend_envelope=true

   Your object should look similar to this:

   `{
     "signers": [
       {

           "name": "Add Name Here",
           "email": "Add Email Here",

           "recipientId": "Add Recipient ID Here",
           "userId": "Add User ID Here",
           "routingOrder": "This number needs to be the same as the agents routing order number",
       }
     ]
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas for you to try out (and **please** comment on this answer about your results!)

**As an agent, search for envelopes awaiting the user's (the agent's) signature**

Use the [Folders: search](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Folders/Folders/search/) method with the special folder name `awaiting_my_signature` Make the API call using [SOBO](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/sobo.html) so the app is acting on behalf of each agent. (You'd make multiple queries, one for each agent.) Or make the app in the form of a User App, each agent would log in and then run the query for himself or herself.

**As the sender of the envelopes, search for envelopes that are not completed, then narrow to the ones awaiting an agent to act**

Again use [Folders: search](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Folders/Folders/search/) method, but send the request as the envelope *sender* (directly or via SOBO). (This assumes that all envelopes are sent by the same user. Or make multiple queries.)

In the search, use the special folder name `out_for_signature`. Include the query parameter `include_recipients=true` Hopefully this will directly give you enough information on the recipients for you to see if the envelope is waiting for an agent. If not, you can use [EnvelopeRecipients: list](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/) to obtain the information.

**Added**

Then the next issue is to enable the Agent to complete his or her action.

Options:

1. Ask the Agent to login to the webtool? They'd then see "Action Required."
2. [Cause the email to be resent to the Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21567330/64904).
3. If you want to programmatically give them the view, I think you'd need to use the [EnvelopeViews: createRecipient](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/)  method--but it only gives a 5 minute URL. You can create a longer lasting URL yourself, [see my answer to another q](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44452163/64904).

Comment: Thank you Larry!  I've looked at both of these methods.  They work good for letting me see the envelopes that are waiting for the agent to assign the next signatory.  I am currently using a webhook to retrieve that information which also works well.  

None of these methods though allow me to send the Agent to the UI where they can assign the signatory.  Or re send them that email if they have deleted it.

I can tell the Agent that they need to add the signatory but they still have to go through the original email to do the assignment.